# how to get window url in modal form's input box

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a html page where there's a login button which opens modal form. Modal form's action is login.php. Once login.php verifies user, I tried to redirect back to parent window from where the modal form originates. Tried having hidden text field etc., Last I tried was to get modal object then access text box. Code is given below html.  Please help.

×
                  
                
            
                
                  **Username**
                  
            
                  **Password**
                  
                    
                  Login
                  
                     Remember me
                  
                
                
             
                
                  Cancel
                  Forgot password?

```
    <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
        var url = window.parent.location;
      
        modal.getElementById('txturl').value = url;
    </script>
```

Comment: Try using very easy way, when modal box opens up and you fill the form, pass the form via ajax, allso once it return true, close the modal box $("#myModal").modal('hide');

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code?

Comment: Thanks Jaymin & Nico Haase   I used login.php to redirect it header("Location: $url");